# How to start import from first numeric column in each row

Tags: shell, awk

I'm very new at this, so I apologize if I'm not clear but I'll try my best. I have a text file with no headers created from a PDF. Each row is a bit different since the first column are the names of the person (and people have different number of names), and after the name come the columns I really care about. The data in the first column I care about always starts with a number. For example, my data looks like:

```
John Paul Apple     8422M   JPA
John Apple       422F   JA
John Paul of the Apple    32245F  JPOTA
John    345222R   J
```

I tried using something like:

```
awk '{$1=""; $2=""; sub("  ", " "); print}' input_filename > output_filename
```

But that results in information I don't want, and loses some I do care about. Is there a command that will consider the first column of each row as the one that starts with a number?

My output file would then look like this:

```
8422M   JPA
422F    JA
32245F  JPOTA
345222R J
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try grep,

```
$ grep -oP '(?: |^)\K\d.*' file
8422M   JPA
422F   JA
32245F  JPOTA
345222R   J

$ grep -oP '(?: |^)\K\d.*' file | column -t
8422M    JPA
422F     JA
32245F   JPOTA
345222R  J
```

**OR**

```
$ grep -o '[0-9].*' file
8422M   JPA
422F   JA
32245F  JPOTA
345222R   J
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm trying this without success. I tried doing: cat input.txt | grep -oP '(?: |^)\K\d.*' > output.txt but I just get a blank file.

Comment: what's the output of `grep -oP '(?: |^)\K\d.*' input.txt` ?

Comment: The output of that is: usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]   I am doing this from the Terminal in case it makes a difference. Thank you so much.

Comment: Tried the update and still get the exact same output as before.

Comment: try without `E`, ie, `grep -o '[0-9].*' file`

Answer (score 2):

And here's an awk version:

```
awk '{sub("^[^0-9]*",""); print}'
```

And if you want the output to look neat,

```
awk '{sub("^[^0-9]*",""); printf "%-12s : %s\n", $1, $2}'
```

**EDIT**

To print a third field neatly, assuming that the second column data will never be more than 8 chars wide,

```
awk '{sub("^[^0-9]*",""); printf "%-12s : %-8s : %s\n", $1, $2, $3}'
```

If some of the 2nd colum stuff is too big, it'll still get printed, pushing the 3rd column data across. `%-8s` means print a `s`tring in a field at least 8 columns wide, aligned to the left, `%8s` would cause the data to be aligned to the right. awk uses standard C printf format specifiers; you can also use them in Python.

Comment: The second line works great! How would I go about importing a third column after the first 2? Tried adding ,$3 without success.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no numbers in the names ("remove from the beginning of the line everything that is not a number"),

```
$ sed 's/^[^0-9]\{1,\}//'  input.txt  
8422M   JPA
422F   JA
32245F  JPOTA
345222R   J
```

Or, either of the following would also work (simplified sed + perl equivalent):

```
$ sed 's/^[^0-9]*//'   input.txt
$ perl -pe 's/^[^0-9]*//'  input.txt
```

Comment: This: "\{1,\}" means "one or more"; if it's an older sed that doesn't understand, then you can also use `'s/^[^0-9][^0-9]*//'`

Comment: Thank you! This gives me the correct output until it gets to a line in which someone has a "-" in their name and then I get sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Comment: @Lucho Really? What OS? (Solaris? try `gsed`) On Linux, it works: `echo 'A-B-C 1234 ABC' | sed 's/^[^0-9]\{1,\}//' =>
`1234 ABC`
`

Comment: I'm using Terminal on OS X. Thanks again!

Comment: ..added simplified sed & perl equivalent... not sure if mac will have issues or not with those. On OSX, I do use/recommend macports so that I have GNU variants of all the common (core) utils. http://www.macports.org/